# How to get ABI of deployed contract using ethersjs in hardhat?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, abi, hardhat-deploy

I have to update my front-end file with deployed latest ABI in json format.
I am using following code in my deploy script (Run after the original smart contract is deployed)

```typescript
import { DeployFunction } from "hardhat-deploy/types";
import { HardhatRuntimeEnvironment } from "hardhat/types";
import fs from "fs";


const updateUI: DeployFunction = async function (hre: HardhatRuntimeEnvironment) {
    const { network, ethers } = hre;
    
    console.log("Writing to front end...");
    
    //Updating ABI on front end JSON file
    const frontEndAbiFile = "path/to/store/abi.json";
    const fundme = await ethers.getContract("FundMe"); //already deployed contract on hardhat/rinkeby
    //I want to get the ABI here so that I can write and save it to frontEndAbiFile location.
    fs.writeFileSync(frontEndAbiFile, 'How shoud I get ABI in json?' );
    
};

export default updateUI;
```

How I can get ABI in json format `FundMe` contract? Please read the comments in my above code.
Note:I am using TypeScript.

Comment: You should look into [TypeChain](https://github.com/dethcrypto/TypeChain)

Answer (score 6):

If you are deploying by command line, you can read from the file where is previously builded, in the case of hardhat there is a example:

```js
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")

const getTheAbi = () => {
  try {
    const dir = path.resolve(
      __dirname,
      "./artifacts/contracts/HelloWorld.sol/HelloWorld.json"
    )
    const file = fs.readFileSync(dir, "utf8")
    const json = JSON.parse(file)
    const abi = json.abi
    console.log(`abi`, abi)

    return abi
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`e`, e)
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the option to get the ABI of already deployed contract on the mainnet?

Answer (score 2):

you can skip ABI to get contract instance directly:

```
const contractInstance = await ethers.getContractAt("contracts/XYZ.sol:ContractName", contractAddress);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fs.writeFileSync(
    frontEndAbiFile,

    fundme.interface.format(ethers.utils.FormatTypes.json)
)
```

When you deploy, this will update your front-end file.

Answer (score 0):

it should be in a project folder like
artifacts/contracts/FundMe/FundMe.json

or on remix

[image: contracts/artifacts/]

Comment: I am developing locally using `hardhat` not on remix.

Comment: good stuff, in which case please refer to the first part of the answer. that's the location in a hardhat proj